# Application.wait in VBA

Tags: excel, wait, vba

I want to add wait time of 1 second in my Application.

---

**What I found online?**

```
newHour = Hour(Now())
   newMinute = Minute(Now())
   newSecond = Second(Now()) + 1
   waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
   Application.Wait waitTime
```

---

**Here is my code**

```
Sub workwithdelay()
Dim i As Integer
Dim done As Integer
Dim newHour As Integer
Dim newMinute As Integer
Dim newSecond As Integer
Dim waitTime As String
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set ws = ActiveSheet

frame = Cells(1, "A").Value


For i = 1 To done

newHour = Hour(Now)
newMinute = Minute(Now)
newSecond = second(Now) + 1
waitTime = newHour: newMinute: newSecond

(ALL of work Code)

Application.Wait waitTime

Next i

End Sub
```

---

The code takes 0.30 seconds to 0.45 seconds to complete one cycle in for loop(not including wait time) depending on the processing of data. I want to add a definite 1 second to complete one for loop cycle no matter what the processing time of the loop is.

Comment: Are you saying that you want each loop to last 1 second? Or that you want each loop to last one second plus the time it takes to execute the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but I think what you want is the `TimeValue` function ([documented here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/timevalue.php)).

You can use it like this:

```
Dim StartTime as Date
Dim EndTime as Date

StartTime =  Now
EndTime = StartTime + TimeValue("00:00:01")
' Do Stuff
Application.Wait EndTime
```

This will cause the application to wait until one second after the *start* of the `Do Stuff` section, which I think is what you are asking for.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different technique with `do...loop + timer`.

```
Sub WaitOneSecond()

    Dim Start as single
        start = timer
    do while start + 1 > timer
       doevents
    loop
end sub
```

and in your original sub call `WaitOnSecond` where necessary:

```
Sub workwithdelay()
(...)

For i = 1 To done
(...)
call WaitOnSecond

Next i

End Sub
```

Some information to above:

1. `timer` counts seconds and milliseconds from midnights of today
2. be careful with my code run just before midnight- it is not correct when new day starts
3. `application.wait` doesn't recognise milliseconds therefore you are not able to get exact 1 second waiting time

Comment: Good catch. I think I misunderstood the OP's problem. I will leave my answer up as it still offers a nice solution for wait times larger than a second.